# Lightweight editor for web.config files

Tags: web-config, text-editor

I'm looking for a lightweight text editor for web.config files which has colour syntax highlighting (like in visual studio).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).  When you work with web.config select XML language to get color syntax highlighting.  It looks like [this](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/screenshots/scrsh_lexerXML.gif).

Comment: Sweet! I already use Notepad++, but didn't know about that feature!

Comment: Check http://www.mattblodgett.com/2007/11/notepad-tip-syntax-highlighting-for.html to find out how to make Notepad++ provide syntax highlighting for web.config all the time:- On the Notepad++ menu bar, click "Settings" -> "Styler Configurator..."


- Under "Language", select "XML" 
- Under "User ext", type in "config".  While we're at it, let's also type in (space delimited) "aspx", "ascx", and "master". 
- Click "Save & Close"

Answer (score 4):

Well obviously you can use any editor (e.g. EditPlus or Notepad++) but if you're looking for a light weight editor client that "knows" what a web.config is have a look at ASPhere

http://blogs.msdn.com/publicsector/archive/2007/12/07/free-utility-web-config-editor-with-a-great-ui.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I use ASPhere. It's great!

> About ASPhere ...
>
> ASPhere is a freeware utility
>   primarily intended for creating and
>   modifying configuration files for
>   ASP.NET. But they are not only
>   web.config files ASPhere can work
>   with, you can use it for viewing and
>   editing normal XML files and plain
>   text files as well.

http://www.asphere.cz/en/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I use [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) for that and many other editing purposes. Freeware, totally usable, quick and light - all you can ask for. Highly recommended.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

in the notepad++

Settings -> Style Configuration -> in the left Listbox select XML -> at bottom the "User ext.:" textbox set "config".

Done

Answer (score 0):

The [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is ultra lightweight, and does `XML` syntax coloring.

> SciTE is a SCIntilla based Text Editor. Originally built to demonstrate Scintilla, it has grown to be a generally useful editor with facilities for building and running programs.

The [download page](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html) says:

> A single file executable called Sc1 (530K) does not need any DLL or properties files as these are linked into the executable.